# How to create database in Android without context?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I know how to create database with context,but how to create it without context?

It's fine Like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.create(null);
```

but it creates a database in memory while I need create the database in file.

So I use 
`SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/appname/databases/temp.db", null)`,it always throw **SQLiteException:unable to open database file**.

Can somebody help me?It drives me crazy.

Comment: I do not have answer to you question, but I am interested why someone need to create the database without context ? I mean what is the advantage if you create database without context ?

Comment: In our application,data store in very low level,and Activity is high level,I don't think low level can know something about higher level.If really can't create without context,may be after Activity creates a database,then pass it to low level can work too?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know file handling needs to be happen with the support of Activity (context). I think its not in the level our (developers) control to change the way android does it.

Comment: excuse me, @McGhost, lucky that I found this post because my requirement is just the same as yours. I wonder which approach you choose finally? and if you use what you mention above, what's the valid path you use? Thanks.